# MySQL say "with" is not valid for this position. I don't understand what the problem here is since the syntax seems to be correct

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join, common-table-expression

```
with emp_cust(id,f_name,l_name) as (
    SELECT 
        c.ID, c.first_name, c.last_name
    FROM
        customer c,
        employee e
    WHERE
        c.first_name = e.first_name
        AND c.last_name = e.last_name
        AND c.email = e.email),
select * from emp_cust.id
```

Comment: You are probably using an older version of MySQL that does not support CTEs.

Comment: Try this query: `SELECT @@version;` If it returns a version 5.x then it doesn't support `WITH` syntax. That feature was added in MySQL 8.0.1.

Comment: Excess comma after CTE.

Comment: there is also an issue with the from clause, you are selecting from `emp_cust.id` that is the column, not CTE

Answer (score 1):

The [`WITH` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) (also called *Common Table Expression*) is supported in MySQL starting version 8.0 only. In earlier versions, you need to use subqueries instead, or other tricks.

The way your query is built, however, there is no benefit using a `WITH` clause whatsoever. You can select directly from the outer query. I would still recommend using standard joins, rather than old-school, implicit joins:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.first_name, c.last_name
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN employee e
    ON  e.first_name = c.first_name
    AND e.last_name  = c.last_name
    AND e.email      = c.email
```

Comment: Indeed, it's anachronistic to see SQL-89 join syntax used in a CTE! :-)